# How can I add to the end of a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a great idea for a homework note pad and I wrote the basics of the program. The problem is that when I add more (I rerun the program) all the contents get wiped out and replaced with the new homework assignment. Is there any way I can fix this?

```
def query_period(agenda_file):
    per = input("What period is it?")

    if per in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]:
        input_and_write_homework(agenda_file)
    else:
        print("Invalid choice")

def input_and_write_homework(file):
    hw = raw_input("What is the homework?")
    file.write(hw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    agenda = open("agenda.txt", "w+")
    query_period(agenda)
    agenda.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To append to a file in python use the 'a' attribute, so change:

```
agenda=open("agenda.txt","w+")
```

to:

```
agenda=open("agenda.txt","a")
```

You should probably be using raw_input() and type cast to a string, instead of input().